# including partial from another admin module and updating a row - Symfony

Tags: symfony1

I have a module, that is just a list of items. Relating to content.
I also have another module, which is a global config sort of module, which has one item in it.

What I'm looking to do, is on the content module, have a checkbox, then when ticked, will update the row in the global config table to set is_published to 1.

How would i go about this?

Could I use a partial or some other way using Ajax?

Comment: I think a bit more information is needed here. A partial and the use of ajax aren't really two options that you put side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom commented this is not really a lot of information and no, partials and ajax aren't both apples. However this is what you could do:

1. Make an AJAX call to an **action** in whichever module is appropriate
2. In that action process the request accordingly:

   - modify a value in a database table
   - modify a value in a config file

Which is the 2 things I assumed could be "global config table".

If you add more info, we can perhaps be more helpful. Thanks!